# Google Cloud ML uploading trained model: Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I have been trying to upload and serve a frozen model based from a GitHub page

https://github.com/Grzego/handwriting-generation

I want to be able to input a string, style and bias to the model and receive co-ords to draw and use on a webpage.

With help from the guy who built it, he created a file that freezes the model to be served. I have seen issues relating to this type of error but not for this 'Exit_1' type.

But on upload of the model, I get the following error

```
Create Version failed. Model validation failed: Outer dimension for outputs must be unknown, outer dimension of 'model_1/while/Exit_1:0' is 1 For more information on how to export Tensorflow SavedModel, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model.
```

Linked below is the file that I used to freeze the model

https://gist.github.com/Grzego/1194da845d6f34fb65862647f60c34b6

I don't know what specifically is the causing this issue, I have tried changing the runtime version since during researching into this issue mentioned to put this to 1.2? but still returns the same problem on any of the versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The service requires that the model be written in such a way that the inputs can be batched, i.e., that the outer dimension of each of the inputs is None. That said, a quick glance at your code shows that the placeholder's outer dimension is None (except for the bias). Can you run `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/model` and provide the output in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the model to work with batch calls as @rhaertel80 has put in his comment.